# Drawing a square that respects layers pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have a `pgfplots` code that generates a paraboloid on top of a circle;

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={30}{60}]

 \addplot [fill=black, domain=0:2*pi,samples=50]({cos(deg(x))},     {sin(deg(x))});
  \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,
 samples=20,
  domain=0:2,y domain=0:2*pi,
  z buffer=sort]
  ({x*cos(deg(y))}, {x*sin(deg(y))}, {x*x});

 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It looks like

[image]

which is nearly what I'm after. I want to draw a square around the circle in the `z=0` plane and be able to fill it (without it covering the circle up) but I cant figure out how to do this.

I tried adding the line

```
 \addplot (-2,2) rectangle (-2,2);
```

but the rectangle generated is in the wrong plane and also doesnt span the points `(-2,-2)`, `(2,2)` like I expected.

Mike

Comment: Like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXcqA.png ?  Or this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/arOQ1.png

Comment: @HarishKumar The latter.

Comment: Answer added...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use suitable coordinates and plot.

```
\addplot+[draw=none,no marks,fill=olive] coordinates{(-2,-2) (2,-2) (2,2) (-2,2)};
```

Put this as the first line before plotting other two.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={30}{60}]     
 \addplot+[draw=none,no marks,fill=olive] coordinates{(-2,-2) (2,-2) (2,2) (-2,2)};      %%<<-- this should come first.
 \addplot [fill=black, domain=0:2*pi,samples=50]({cos(deg(x))},     {sin(deg(x))});
  \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,
 samples=20,
  domain=0:2,y domain=0:2*pi,
  z buffer=sort]
  ({x*cos(deg(y))}, {x*sin(deg(y))}, {x*x});

 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]